# How to change null pointer (of struct return type) to declared struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to C programming. I am trying to implement Linked list by myself. I am encountering problem with pointers

I have function

```
void Insert(Node* head, int x)
```

to insert node at the beginning of Linked list. The problem is that when I insert the very first node and Node *head is NULL, the function Insert is not able to change the pointer address of null pointer to the newly created node. It seems as if the Node *head is passed by value and not by reference. 
  Code is provided below. In order to debug how address is changed throughout the execution, I used printf function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

int main() {
    Node *head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head = NULL;

    printf("head in main(): %d\n", head); // For example: 100

    Insert(head, 25);
    return 0;
}

void Insert(Node *head, int x) {
    Node *temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;

    printf("temp->next address: %d\n", temp->next); // also 100

    head = temp;

    printf("%d\n", head); // not 100, something else i.e  200
}
```

Comment: Pass in a pointer to `head`, and change the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: "It seems as if the Node *head is passed by value and not by reference."  Indeed.  **Everything** in C is passed by value

Comment: Thomas Jager, do you mean:
head->data = temp->data
head->next = temp->next
?

Comment: `head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node)); head = NULL;` Wow. Just allocate the memory and immediately throw it away. Talk about memory leaks.

Comment: You could bypass the confusion and pointer-to-pointer stuff by creating a struct for the linked list and passing around a pointer to that: `struct LinkedList {Node *head;};`

Comment: You can also bypass the pointer-to-pointer stuff by returning the new `head` from the function. So the function declaration should be `Node *Insert(Node *head, int x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems as if the Node *head is passed by value and not by reference.

That is exactly right -- in C every parameter is always passed by value. The *pointer* is a value, and that value is passed by value, and the call

```
Insert(head, 25);
```

can never change the *value* of the variable named `head`. It *reads the value* of the variable (this value is a null pointer), gives that value to the function and never touches the *variable* `head` again no matter what the function does.

(Note that in your program you have two variables that are both named `head` -- one in `main()` and the other in `Insert()`. The variable in `Insert()` silently disappears when the function returns; nothing will automatically try to copy its value to the similarly-named variable in `main()`).

If you want to (conceptually) pass `head` *by reference*, you need to actually pass a pointer to it -- that is, in this case, a pointer to a pointer! You'd need to declare your function as

```
void Insert(Node **head, int x) { ... }
```

and call it as

```
Insert(&head, 25);
```

Then the actual parameter is a pointer to the variable `head` which gives the function a chance to update that variable, if you deference the parameter where appropriate:

```
// ...
temp->next = *head;
// ...
*head = temp;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have one more question. Some one in the comment above has told me that by declaring dynamic memory and throwing it away, I am creating memory leak. Question is: Should I create head node in heap or stack?

Comment: @Genjik: JL2210's comment is right -- if you want to start with an empty list, that list consists only of the NULL pointer and _no_ instances of `struct Node`. So it makes no sense for you to start by allocating a `struct Node` just to forget about it again afterwards. The allocation within your `Insert` method is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Pass a pointer to a pointer to head. That way, you can set head to null.

```c
void Insert(Node **head, int x) {

    ...

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp;
    }

    else {
        ...
        *head->next = temp;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```c
Node *head = NULL;
Insert(&head, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Having three answers suggesting the same I would like to offer an alternative: 
Instead of passing a `Node **` to `Insert()` you could instead have it return the new `head`, thus:

```
Node *Insert( Node *head, int x )
{
     ... your code ...
     return head;
}
```

and if you call it by

```
head = Insert( head, 24 );
```

That is neither better nor worse then the other solution so you my do whatever you prefer

Comment: "Neither better nor worse" in what sense? It is not exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

There are number of issues here.
1. Your printf statements need to be corrected.
2. To insert function you can pass double pointer.
3. Inside main function, you need not to do `Node *head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));`

I have modified your code as shown below. You can try running it and co-relate above points.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void Insert(Node **head, int x);

void Insert(Node **head, int x) {
    Node *temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = *head;

    printf("temp->next address: %d\n", temp->data); // also 100

    *head = temp;

    printf("%d\n", (*head)->data); // not 100, something else i.e  200
}

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;
    head = NULL;

    Insert(&head, 25);
    printf("head in main(): %d\n", head->data); // For example: 100
    return 0;
}
```